# How can I can type inference for the return type of a generic function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a class that encapsulates some Api calling function to keep my Vue pages cleaner. I would like to be able to initialize this class with the api call method and then be able to call it through the class and get the return type of the function.
This is what I have so far

```
class ApiCall<T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => Promise<TResponce>, TResponce> {

  private Request: T
  public IsCalling = false
  public HasErrors = false
  public Error: HttpError | null = null
  public IsSuccessful = false

  constructor (request: T) {
    this.Request = request
  }

  Call (...callArgs: Parameters<T>): TResponce | null {
    this.IsSuccessful = false
    this.Error = null
    this.HasErrors = false
    this.IsCalling = true

    this.Request(...callArgs)
    .then((result) => {
      this.IsSuccessful = true
      return result
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.Error = error
      this.HasErrors = true
    }).finally(() => {
      this.IsCalling = false
    })

    return null
  }

  public GetErrors (key: string): string[] | null {
    return this.Error?.ModelState?.[key] ?? null
  }
}
```

And then when I want to run the function I am trying:

```
var blogApiCall = new ApiCall(Services.API.Blogs.GetBlogBySlug)
var result = blogApiCall.Call('slug')
```

> result will be any.

I have also tried to the return type to be ReturnType:

```
class ApiCall<T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>> {
```

But because the 'Call' method needs the 'Request' to be a promise I am receiving the error:

> Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ReturnType'

What's interesting is that I got return types to work in this earlier iteration but not parameters

```
class ApiCall2<T> {

  private Request: (...parameters: any) => Promise<T>
  public IsCalling = false
  public HasErrors = false
  public Error: HttpError | null = null
  public IsSuccessful = false

  constructor (request: (...parameters: any) => Promise<T>) {
    this.Request = request
  }

  Call (...parameters: any): T | null {
    this.IsSuccessful = false
    this.Error = null
    this.HasErrors = false
    this.IsCalling = true

    this.Request(parameters)
    .then((result) => {
      this.IsSuccessful = true
      return result
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.Error = error
      this.HasErrors = true
    }).finally(() => {
      this.IsCalling = false
    })

    return null
  }

  public GetErrors (key: string): string[] | null {
    return this.Error?.ModelState?.[key] ?? null
  }
}
```

Semi new to Typescript and brand new to Stack Overflow so any helpful advice would be well received.

Thanks heaps

Comment: Side note: `result` value would actually always be `null`, because you do not wait for or return the Promise.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I'm waiting for the promise to resolve in the Call method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE. That lets us get to work on your problem instead of trying to re-create it. (e.g., What's `HttpError` and `Services`?) Try to remove code that isn't needed to reproduce things; to a first approximation: the less code there is, the easier it is to focus on the code with the problem. Also it helps to stick with common naming conventions, to reduce distractions. Property and method names are conventionally in `lowerPascalCase` and not `UpperPascalCase`.  Good luck!

Comment: If I try to fix all that I get something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w61lDW).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining it (although I'd appreciate it if you would [edit] the code to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP93Yw) (naming conventions, defined things, etc) and mention how you're getting `unknown` instead of `any` (and if you *are* getting `any`, please show the code that demonstrates this).  If it does not meet your needs, what am I missing?  Oh, and please mention @jcalz if you reply to me, otherwise I won't be notified.